# Reading Arduino by serial monitor and Java at the same time

Tags: java, serial-port, port, arduino, serial-communication

I've written a code in java to communicate with my Arduino board. It works well. Also I can use the serial monitor to communicate with the Arduino board.

But when I try to open serial monitor, while the java program is running (listening on the port which is connected to thee board, *PORT 32*), it fails saying,

`Serial port 'COM 32' already in use. Try quitting any programs that may be using it.`

This is the complete message (just for the sake of completeness)

```
Binary sketch size: 3,994 bytes (of a 258,048 byte maximum)
processing.app.SerialException: Serial port 'COM32' already in use. Try quiting any programs that may be using it.
    at processing.app.Serial.<init>(Serial.java:171)
    at processing.app.Serial.<init>(Serial.java:92)
    at processing.app.SerialMonitor.openSerialPort(SerialMonitor.java:207)
    at processing.app.Editor.handleSerial(Editor.java:2447)
    at processing.app.EditorToolbar.mousePressed(EditorToolbar.java:353)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6260)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6028)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4574)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4235)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2475)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Yeah I know, its my java program which is using the port. But does that mean that I can't use both programs at the same time to access PORT32?

Hope someone will show me a way around this. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your observation is correct, serial ports can only be opened by one application at a time. There are software solutions available to split serial ports, or monitor them, but I am not experienced enough with those to give any recommendations.

Comment: you told what I was afraid to accept. But what if that's the truth :( . Then I guess this is not a Java or Arduino problem anymore. Well.. I'll respond soon. (I may get some other ideas)